# Pegar valor do conjunto da direita com campos 'ambíguos'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, join

Estou fazendo a seguinte consulta ao meu banco de dados:

```
  $escalacoes = 'SELECT * FROM escalacoes AS e JOIN jogador_rodada AS jr ON e.id_jogador = jr.id_jogador WHERE
    e.rodada = ('.$rodada_atual.' - 0) AND jr.rodada = '.$rodada_atual;
  $escalacoes = $pdo->query($escalacoes);
  $escalacoes->execute();
  while ($dadoEscalacao = $escalacoes->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $dadoEscalacao['rodada'];
    echo "<br>";
  }
```

1. A "$rodada_atual" tá definida em outro lugar
2. Aquele "- 0" é apenas porque no meu teste eu tenho que usar assim

Quando eu imprimo no php a rodada, ele pega o valor da tabela da ***esquerda*** (no caso, a tabela ***'escalacoes'***). Sendo que tenho uma coluna com esse mesmo nome na outra tabela (***'jogador_rodada'***).
Tem como eu imprimir esse o valor da tabela da direita no próprio php?

Imagem demonstrativa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

obs: eu sei que não preciso disso, já que estou determinando o valor da rodada na query sql, mas me surgiu essa dúvida de saber se é possível fazer isso.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122/select-all-columns-except-one-in-mysql da uma olhada aqui, talvez fazendo o select sem contar a coluna com mesmo nome q vc não quer resolva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar um `ALIAS` para aquele campo que você quer resgatar. Ou seja, um nome alternativo para o campo. Assim:

```
$escalacoes = 'SELECT e.id, e.id_user, e.id_jogador, e.preco, e.status,
jr.id_jogador AS id_jogador_direita, jr.id, jr.valor, jr.pontos, jr.status, jr.rodada
FROM escalacoes AS e 
JOIN jogador_rodada AS jr ON e.id_jogador = jr.id_jogador 
WHERE
e.rodada = ('.$rodada_atual.' - 0) AND jr.rodada = '.$rodada_atual;
```

Com esse alias `jr.id_jogador AS id_jogador_direita` você irá conseguir selecionar o campo desejado assim:

```
$escalacoes = $pdo->query($escalacoes);
  $escalacoes->execute();
  while ($dadoEscalacao = $escalacoes->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $dadoEscalacao['id_jogador_direita'];
    echo "<br>";
  }
```

Comment: Obrigado. Exatamente isso!

Comment: @VME tranquilo! =)